# Tabs are all over the place. Is this normal?

Tags: routes

Tabs in drupal are all over the place for my site. Is this normal? Clicking through the tabs on the same node constantly alternates between overlay (pop up) layer and the non-overlay layer, as below.

I can't help but think about how difficult and annoying this will be for the content authors, and am not looking forward to the questions they are going to ask me about the constant switching of the windows and layers.

Is there a way to standardise this behaviour, as opposed it being all over the place?

http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/8640/tabsiz.png

[image]

Comment: What specifically is your problem?  How do you want to standardize the behavior?  If you don't like the overlay, why not just disable the overlay?

Comment: Perhaps your theme is interfering with overlay, try a different theme and see if it persists? Otherwise simply disable overlay module as @PatrickKenny suggested

Comment: Thank you @PatrickKenny
But, even if I disable the overlay module, the screens are not consistent, one displays across the whole screen while others are displayed in the main content area...

Comment: Thanks @Neograph734

Is there a way to make the admin screen to only ever display in the main content area of the page, while always preserving the left hand nav, header and footer menus?

Comment: Yes there is, you can set it at the bottom of `/admin/appearance`. If you choose your default theme there, all blocks will remain as they are. Depending on the theme though, it might cripple your site when viewing large tables like the permissions page `/admin/people/permissions`